# Solving a Second Order Constant Matrix Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given that $A$ is a constant coefficient matrix, how would one find a non-zero solution to the following equation: $$ x''+2Ax'+A^2x=0 $$
I am thinking this could incorporate systems of linear equations, but I am not sure how to use $x'=Ax$ or $x'=P(t)x +g(t)$ in this situation.

Any hints or suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Set $u(t)=e^{tA}x(t)$ to find $u'(t)=e^{tA}(x'(t)+Ax(t))$ and
$$
u''(t)=e^{tA}(x''(t)+2Ax'(t)+A^2x(t))=0
$$
so that you find the solution as 
$$
x(t)=e^{-tA}(Ct+D)
$$
just as in the scalar case. Indeed, all computations take place in the matrix sub-ring generated by $A$, and as that is commutative, it can be treated analogous to the scalar case.

---

If you just want an first order system to analyze with standard methods, set $v=x'+Ax$, then
\begin{align}
x'&=v-Ax\\
v'&=x''+Ax'=-(Ax'+A^2x)=-Av
\end{align}

Comment: How do you know to set $v = x'+Ax$? Where does this formula for $v$ come from?

Comment: Because your equation is $(D+A)^2y=0$ it makes sense to use the factorization in the first order system, $(D+A)y=v$, $(D+A)v=0$.